# openDMARC Authentication Result: fail

Tags: gmail, postfix-mta, email-headers

I have problem with opendmarc and gmail (gmail put mails from my servers to spam).
I read many forums and topics but anywhere I can't find solutions for my problem.
If I try mail-tester.com I have 10/10 but gmail still accept my mails.

If I check mail There is:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of madaraszko@mydomain.com designates 11.22.33.44 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=madaraszko@mydomain.com;
   dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.com
Received: by mail.mydomain.com (Postfix, from userid 111)
id A4F4160598; Thu, 28 Apr 2016 10:29:48 +0200 (CEST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.com; s=mail;
t=1461832188; bh=8fggacpyUWh5Kr8oMgY87yEuuCmYt5ETnFZxhdP9YIE=;
h=From:Subject:Date:References:To:From;
b=B24WlYMHGLqC8d+B5MnBByWUg+zkKqfRSiiRP0pahD5bHGvNCOFCpBkWlklu8pjmJ
 oKyShimi91qFf7IcPrvkP4UCAB0KPTR+LX3n4S7pV54JIKXr7hkLQENqsgWiE9CjlU
 ijd7JXTp0FZH0SKSh1Un24Pv4bPKl0j10j4OG6A4=
Received: from [10.238.2.155] (mail.otherdomain.com [44.55.66.77])
by mail.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 7FCFC60555
for <xxxx@gmail.com>; Thu, 28 Apr 2016 10:29:46 +0200 (CEST)
Authentication-Results: mydomain.com; dmarc=fail header.from=mydomain.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.com; s=mail;
t=1461832186; bh=8fggacpyUWh5Kr8oMgY87yEuuCmYt5ETnFZxhdP9YIE=;
h=From:Subject:Date:References:To:From;
b=acvw+r2aUiHroR6h/D+NzgRnRWFeci84Vot+gcQJ5vfom2y13QH/3P9mvkUCq230H
 sPBDR0Ov3B6b0vz12MUgCXO/lqRGKpKWKWTE+5Z0VY5a6EUrwNo1Rr8Q5EO5Ymjhkf
 5Z3SgXHsUUjBeiwuI0AlEa646PMjRgqwqE4skp+U=
```

in my log on the mail server is

```
Apr 28 10:34:52 mail opendmarc[23264]: implicit authentication service:   mydomain.com
Apr 28 10:34:52 mail opendmarc[23264]: 33EE560555: mydomain.com fail
```

My opendmarc.conf

```
AuthservID mydomain.com
PidFile /var/run/opendmarc.pid #Debian default
RejectFailures false
Syslog true
TrustedAuthservIDs mydomain.com
UMask 0002
UserID opendmarc:opendmarc
IgnoreHosts /etc/opendmarc/ignore.hosts
HistoryFile /var/run/opendmarc/opendmarc.dat
```

File ignore.hosts

```
localhost
```

What should I check or change?
I have postfix dovecot spamassasin opendkim and opendmarc

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

Adding

```
IgnoreAuthenticatedClients true
```

to the opendmarc.conf did help me.  I also have all local IPs (IPv4+IPv6 range and ::1) in my ignore.hosts file, but that didn't help.

Comment: You only answer part of OP's question.  Once you reach 50 reputation you will be able to comment on questions, comments are the correct way to handle such additions.  For now consider reading the [formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), better formatted answers and/or comments have greater chances of being useful since they're more readable.